# Graphviz (neato) segfault when processing tree with 50,000 vertices

Tags: charts, visualization, segmentation-fault, graphviz, sage

I have a 5MB .gv file with the edges for a 50,000 node tree. I've run neato on it (with a few output formats). The .gv file was generated by [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org) (built-in `Graph.show` method was not terminating).

All I get is the following:

```
neato(2258,0x108a0d5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug out of memory
fish: 'neato 11.gv -Tsvg > 11.svg' terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Is this size graph too big for graphviz to handle? I imagine layout for a dense graph of this size would be very messy/slow, even infeasible, but I assumed a tree would be easy to layout. I can think of some very straightforward layout algorithms off the top of my head; I'd just prefer to use a command line tool I have installed.

Also if anyone thinks another SE site would be a better fit, please add a comment, thanks!

edit:

I just found out about sfdp. I will try that and post an answer if problem's solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that switching to `sfdp` solved this problem. Output is generated in less than a minute (though not readable with default settings; will have to fiddle with that).